# maxDPD in last 6 months based on account

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have these columns: year_month (201403,201404,...201602,201603), ID_account (123,456,789), DPD (some numbers). For ID_account I need to find max_DPD in last 6 months as max_DPD. Like this (SSMS2008):

```
 year_month || ID_account || DPD || max_DPD
  ----------------------------------------------------
   201403     || 123        || 30  || 30
   201404     || 123        || 0   || 30
   201405     || 123        || 45  || 45
   201406     || 123        || 1   || 45
   201403     || 456        || 0   || 0
   201404     || 456        || 12  || 12
   201405     || 456        || 20  || 20
   201406     || 456        || 0   || 20
   201403     || 789        || 0   || 0
```

Comment: please paste the expected output for above data

Comment: expected output is column max_DPD